# How to use FIND_IN_SET() with non-comma separation?

Tags: mysql

Find in set works great for what I am searching for but sadly the field is separated by a different char(set -> |*|)? Can I change the separator for the find somehow?

Answer (score 8):

you can use REPLACE and then FIND_IN_SET

```
   FIND_IN_SET('ddd' ,REPLACE(str, '|*|', ',') )
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11216/1)

Comment: I don't agree. What if the data is `1,2,3|*|4,5,6` ? It will have bad side effect.